# Cross building sys based crates

Tags: gcc, rust, arm64, musl

I try to cross building some rust package with their `-sys` crates.
The host is x86_64 (Ubuntu 22.04
) and target is aarch64 (Alpine)

So I use these crate with vendored flag enabled to build them.
I install musl-tools and musl-dev on the host, because Alpine doesn't use libc.

But get:

```
error occurred: Failed to find tool. Is `aarch64-linux-musl-gcc` installed?
```

I setup `rustup target add aarch64-unknown-linux-musl` before building my app

So `aarch64-linux-musl-gcc` must be installed trough `musl-tools` ? or I have to install something else ?

Comment: `aarch64-linux-musl-gcc` is the C compiler for the `aarch64-linux-musl` target. It is used for linking applications with the libraries (including the system libraries). So you need to install it too, but I don't know how to do that on Windows.

Comment: I work from Ubuntu x86_64

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the `aarch64-unknown-linux-musl` target; I don't think `aarch64-linux-musl-gcc` is even a thing.

Try installing the target for your current toolchain:

```
rustup target add aarch64-unknown-linux-musl
```

and then building for *that* source:

```
cargo build --release --target aarch64-unknown-linux-musl
```

Also, if you're building for this target from Windows, it's almost undoubtedly easier to do it from WSL2.

Further NB: While I have never built for `aarch64`, I *have* tried to build `openssl` for an `x86_64-unknown-linux-musl` Alpine target, and I've never gotten it to work. I have no idea what your application is, but if you have trouble building `openssl` even with the correct target, you might see if you can use [`rustls`](https://docs.rs/rustls/latest/rustls/) instead.

Comment: I already do `rustup target add aarch64-unknown-linux-musl`  before building my app. And There is also lzma-sys, zstd-sys and brotli-sys into my app deps

Comment: Okay, but my point is that your error message suggests that you're trying (intentionally or no) to build for a target that doesn't exist, and you should try building for the `aarch64-unknown-linux-musl` target instead.

Comment: The cargo command target arg is `aarch64-unknown-linux-musl` so I guess cargo modify this arg during building ?

Comment: Have you tried building this from WSL instead of in the native Windows environment?

Comment: I use Ubuntu 22.04, not Windows

Comment: Then I don't know what you meant by "The host is x86_64 (Windows) and target is aarch64 (Alpine)". Can you post verbatim the command you used and the entirety of the response you got?